# Magento - Website content is disabled on some sizes of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento2

When I resize the browser window width (approximate range: 950-770), my website content (text, links, buttons) is going disabled. Let me know if you need any specific details.

Comment: I had the same issue some time back and it was not working on ipad and iphones.

Comment: Yes. What are you talking about? Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the intended behavior of your theme. Many themes will hide certain non essential elements on mobile. If you'd like more details, use the inspect element of your browser and you'll be able to see which styles are causing the elements to hide. You can then override these in your own stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking into the CSS.